# Modify CW value in mac802.11.h in NS2

Tags: ns2, contention, wifi

I'm trying to modify the cw_ value in the mac-802.11.h file, with no luck.

Normally this is how it is done, `cw_=(cw_<<1)+1`.

This is what I tried, `cw_=(cw_ * 1.8)+1`.

The above had no change in result with respect to the average throughput and the average packets dropped after simulation.

Am I missing out something? or is it that the CW value can only be modified in a binary fashion.

I am using 10 nodes in an environment of 500x500. One TCP agent and FTP application is used in TCL. The nodes move randomly whereas the TCP agent and the sink are connected to their respective nodes in the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

The cw can't exceed predefined size, it's being rounded down to it if this occurs. Maybe in your case this is what happens in both calculations.

You should also be aware that `cw_` is uint32 type so multiplication it by 1.8 (double) might get you the result you're not expecting.